# Super Beginner Code Confusion

Tags: python

```
n = input("What is your number")
if n > 0:
    print("It's Bigger Than 0")
else:
    print("It's smaller than 0")
```

why does this give an error
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Because `n` is a string and `0` is a number.

Comment: You need to convert your input to an integer: `n = int(input("What is your number"))`

Comment: BTW, 0 isn't smaller than 0.

Answer (score -1):

Change the first line to:

```
n = int(input("What is your number"))
```

In Python 3, `input` always returns a string.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted...twice too lol

Comment: @smac89 I think some people downvote answers to duplicate questions, even though I answered before it was marked as a duplicate.